# Handling concurrency in Liferay Cluster

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, liferay, cluster-computing

I am working in a **LR 6.2 CE GA4** Clustered environment.
The 2 nodes share the same DB with shared cache via portal-ext cluster configuration.

I have a scheduler invoking the method *processMe()* every 15 mins which can also be invoked by a user on clicking a page.

My requirement is to restrict concurrent call to this method.
I understand that synchronized blocks wont work due to the different JVMs.

Is there anything which I can reuse OOTB from within Liferay ? 
Can I reuse something from the JGroups Unicast/Multicast communication ?

Any other suggestions ?

**Posted in liferay forum :** https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/74168121

Thanks,

Siby Mathew

Comment: Where would you like to get the answer? Here? Or on Liferay's Forum? Elsewhere? Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site and update/link/delete accordingly

Comment: I added a link to my post in liferay forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution after referring the method : **com.liferay.portal.kernel.backgroundtask.SerialBackgroundTaskExecutor.acquireLock()**

Here is the code :

```
    @Override
    public BackgroundTaskResult execute(BackgroundTask backgroundTask)
        throws Exception {

    Lock lock = null;

    String owner =
        backgroundTask.getName() + StringPool.POUND +
            backgroundTask.getBackgroundTaskId();

    try {
        if (isSerial()) {
            lock = acquireLock(backgroundTask, owner);
        }

        BackgroundTaskExecutor backgroundTaskExecutor =
            getBackgroundTaskExecutor();

        return backgroundTaskExecutor.execute(backgroundTask);
    }
    finally {
        if (lock != null) {
            LockLocalServiceUtil.unlock(
                BackgroundTaskExecutor.class.getName(),
                backgroundTask.getTaskExecutorClassName(), owner);
        }
    }
}  

 protected Lock acquireLock(BackgroundTask backgroundTask, String owner)
        throws DuplicateLockException {

    Lock lock = null;

    while (true) {
        try {
            lock = LockLocalServiceUtil.lock(
                BackgroundTaskExecutor.class.getName(),
                backgroundTask.getTaskExecutorClassName(), owner);

            break;
        }
        catch (SystemException se) {
            if (_log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                _log.debug("Unable to acquire acquiring lock", se);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }

    if (!lock.isNew()) {
        throw new DuplicateLockException(lock);
    }

    return lock;
}
```

The major change in my code was to check

```
if (!lock.isNew()) {
 throw new DuplicateLockException(lock);
}
```

Basically even if two threads are able to invoke the lock() method (which I was testing by firing two schedulers concurrently), only one of the thread will be successful in creating the new object and the other will be just fetching the existing lock object.

Hence **lock.isNew()** should find the thread which is holding the real lock.

Thanks,

Siby Mathew